# Facing IntelliSense Issue in Visual studio 2012 for includes with system variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I migrated c++ solution with multiple projects from VS2010 to VS2012. 
Projects have reference of libraries with path set as System variables.

Application is getting compiled and run. But Intellisense reporting errors for all symbols and header in libraries. In External Dependencies node in solution explorer, it is not showing header files of 3rd Party libraries.
Headers file with hard coded and relative paths don't have this issue.

When right clicked on Header declaration to open header files, it shows all paths specified in project by striping environment variable values. e.g.
if include paths are "C:\QT\Includes;..\..\VISLIB\Inc;$(PROBAL_SHT_LIB)\V18.05\Inc", then it will show message "File 'XX.h" not found in ....... Build system path:
C:\QT\Includes;..\..\VISLIB\Inc;\V18.05\Inc.
and strips $(PROBAL_SHT_LIB).

Also noticed that if I set new system variable, then it is not shown in "Macros". or code is not getting compiled with VS2012. To make VS2012 recognize this variable. I need to restart PC.

This was working fine with VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that the frontend/parser used by intellisense is not the same as that used by the actual compiler.
They are not always updated in sync and they often have different levels of feature completeness and different bugs. Thus it is not uncommon for intellisense to complain about perfectly valid code that the real compiler will handle just fine.
That is, of course, not great - but it is a fact and noone but Microsoft can do anything about it.

Comment: Completely agree.. but I need to make it working for some libraries that are frequently changing so need to know new functions and changes signatures. Otherwise development time will increase greatly.

Comment: @Abhay Joshi you should go talk to Microsoft if you are not happy with intellisense - they are the only ones who can improve it (as my answer stated).